# Python check if list item is in text file

Tags: python, json, text

```
output_file = open("processed.txt", "a")

with open('text.json') as json_file:
        object_list = json.load(json_file)


receive_txids = []
for object in object_list:
        if object['category'] == 'receive':
                receive_txids.append(object['txid'])



with open('list.txt', "r") as list_file:
        for txid in receive_txids:
                if txid not in list_file:
                        print "for ea txid " + txid

                        print "NEW TRANSACTION";
                        output_file.write(txid + '\n')
```

that's my code

this is list.txt contents

```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```

text.json looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "account" : "",
        "address" : "D8xWhR8LqSdSLTxRWwouQ3EiSnvcjLmdo6",
        "category" : "receive",
        "amount" : 1000.00000000,
        "confirmations" : 1963,
        "blockhash" : "4569322b4c8c98fba3ef4c7bda91b53b4ee82d268eae2ff7658bc0d3753c00ff",
        "blockindex" : 2,
        "blocktime" : 1394242415,
        "txid" : "45b629a779e6e0bf6d160c37833a27f1f2cc1bfa34632d166cccae83e69eb6fe",
        "time" : 1394242265,
        "timereceived" : 1394242265
    },
    {
        "account" : "",
        "address" : "D8xWhR8LqSdSLTxRWwouQ3EiSnvcjLmdo6",
        "category" : "receive",
        "amount" : 11.00000000,
        "confirmations" : 1194,
        "blockhash" : "eff3d32177bf19629fe0f8076807acbb02b34aedcbce1c27a19ce9872daecb7c",
        "blockindex" : 6,
        "blocktime" : 1394290663,
        "txid" : "bf5b7bc1aeaf7fb43f5d39b549278bee6665872bd74274dd5fad80d043002a3e",
        "time" : 1394290582,
        "timereceived" : 1394290582
    },
    {
        "account" : "",
        "address" : "DKLMkLZmiSVXtEavDpQ4dasjZvC178QoM9",
        "category" : "receive",
        "amount" : 1.00000000,
        "confirmations" : 1183,
        "blockhash" : "7b5d3ebeb994dbff0940504db9e407bd90cad8a5a1ace05dcba4bc508ca27aff",
        "blockindex" : 9,
        "blocktime" : 1394291510,
        "txid" : "1e5f49fa1d0df059b9d7da8452cde9fb5a312c823401f5ed4ed4eafb5f98c1b0",
        "time" : 1394291510,
        "timereceived" : 1394291578
    },
    {
        "account" : "",
        "address" : "DKLMkLZmiSVXtEavDpQ4dasjZvC178QoM9",
        "category" : "receive",
        "amount" : 1.00000000,
        "confirmations" : 1179,
        "blockhash" : "4d9bd6d2988bc749022c41d125f1134796aa314e0d0bde34eba855ad88e76a7f",
        "blockindex" : 21,
        "blocktime" : 1394291642,
        "txid" : "7dc7cd4afcebaf8f17575be8b9acf06adcaadfe7fa5528453246307aa36e6ea0",
        "time" : 1394291629,
        "timereceived" : 1394291629
    },
    {
        "account" : "",
        "address" : "DKLMkLZmiSVXtEavDpQ4dasjZvC178QoM9",
        "category" : "receive",
        "amount" : 1.00000000,
        "confirmations" : 1179,
        "blockhash" : "4d9bd6d2988bc749022c41d125f1134796aa314e0d0bde34eba855ad88e76a7f",
        "blockindex" : 20,
        "blocktime" : 1394291642,
        "txid" : "aefdb89b461c118529bec78b35fed46cc5d7050b39902552fa2408361284c746",
        "time" : 1394291637,
        "timereceived" : 1394291637
    },
    {
        "account" : "",
        "address" : "DKLMkLZmiSVXtEavDpQ4dasjZvC178QoM9",
        "category" : "receive",
        "amount" : 11.00000000,
        "confirmations" : 34,
        "blockhash" : "df34d9d44e87cd3315755d3e7794b10729fc3f5853c218ec237c43a89d918eb7",
        "blockindex" : 5,
        "blocktime" : 1394364125,
        "txid" : "ec6abb67828c79cbf0b74131f0acfddc509efc9743bed0811d2316007cdcc482",
        "time" : 1394348464,
        "timereceived" : 1394348464
    }
]
```

I cannot for the life of me find out why this isn't working. It's printing "NEW TRANSACTION" every time it iterates through.

I want to check for each txid (transaction id) in json.txt, if it already exists in list.txt. If not, I want to write it to "processed.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File objects don't support containment tests; you'd need to read your text file.

It'd be easiest for you to put all transaction ids in a set, then remove all txids found in your `list.txt` using set operations. Whatever is left are new transactions to write to the file:

```
with open('text.json') as json_file:
    recieve_txids = {o['txid'] for o in json.load(json_file) if o['category'] == 'recieve'}

with open('list.txt', "r") as list_file:
    recieve_txids -= {l.strip() for l in list_file}

with open('processed.txt', "w") as output_file:
    for txid in recieve_txids:
        output_file.write(txid + '\n')
```

If you needed access to the original JSON objects still, use a dictionary, with the `txid` as the key, then remove all elements from the dictionary found in the file:

```
with open('text.json') as json_file:
    recieve_txids = {o['txid']: o for o in json.load(json_file) if o['category'] == 'recieve'}

with open('list.txt', "r") as list_file:
    for line in list_file:
        txid = l.strip()
        if txid in recieve_txids:
            del recieve_txids[txid]
```

Comment: should the last "with open" be for "processed transactions" because that's where I want to write to :P

Comment: @Andy: ah, yes, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: Once I have the txids (in processed.txt) how can I get information like address, amount with the corresponding txid?

Comment: You could produce an index from the JSON file; a dictionary with `txid` keys and the whole transaction object as the value.

Comment: How would I go about getting the index for it? Once I have that I know what to do :)

Comment: @Andy: there, I've added such a dictionary for you; it replaces the set, but the `for txid in recieve_txids:` loop will still operate the same.

Comment: Sorry, I've never user and don't know what a dictionary is. Would it be easier to just use an index?

Answer (score 0):

The `open()` function returns an iterator not a list so you can use the `in` operator only once. Repeatedly using `in` on the same iterator only checks an empty list returned by a file already having reached is end.

Furthermore each line still contains the trailing line separator characters so you should use `strip('\n\r')` to get rid of them.

And to quickly check if an item is in a list you should use a `set`.

Something like this should work:

```
transaction_ids = set()
with open('list.txt', 'r') as list_file:
    for line in list_file:
        transaction_ids.add(line.rstrip('\n\r')

for txid in receive_txids:
    if txid not in transaction_ids:
        print "NEW TRANSACTION";
```